# Finitely generated ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am reading this definition:
We say that an ideal $I$ is $k$-generated, where $k$ is a cardinal number, i.e., the minimal cardinality of generating sets of $I$.

Further, A non-zero ideal is finitely generated if it is $n$-generated for some positive integer $n$. I am not understanding why $n$ should be a positive integer?

What is a non-zero ideal that is 0-generated?
Would you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't exist. A $0$-generated ideal is the ideal $\{0\}$ . On the other hand, ‘positive’ *may* mean $\ge 0$ – it's a matter of convention.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal with zero generators would necessarily be the zero ideal (because of the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) convention), but by convention (and, I guess, convenience, since it makes it more explicit which ring it is an ideal of; the empty set generates all zero ideals in all rings simultaneously), we say the zero ideal is generated by $\{0\}$.

Comment: You can actually avoid the empty sum convention - if you define an ideal generated by $A$ as the smallest (in terms of inclusion) ideal containing $A$, then clearly, the zero ideal is generated by an empty set.

Comment: @ Arthur Thank you for your answer. In your last statement" we say that the zero ideal is generated by {0}", should it be by an empty set?  Now, can we say that a non-zero ideal is $n$-generated for $n\in\mathbf{N}$?

Comment: @User1999 No, $\{0\}$ is not the empty set. It is the set containing $0\in R$. It is theconventional generating set for the zero ideal in $R$.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for your reply. I mean by the empty sum convention can we say that the ideal {0} is generated by an empty set?

Comment: @User1999 Yes, we could (or as 5xum says above, even without empty sum convention), but we don't. I have started what I _think_ is the reason above, but I don't know with any kind of certainty.